# Custom partials in exception notification in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, exception

I am trying to set up a custom partial for my exception notification mails in a Rails 3 app using the current version (2.4.0) of the [exception_notification gem](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification)

The README clearly states that "you can customize how each of those
sections are rendered by placing a partial named for that part in your
app/views/exception_notifier directory [...] You can even add new sections that
describe application-specific data"

And I am exactly trying these: Altering existing sections and adding a new custom section. When just altering a section, my changed partial (app/views/exception_notifier/_session.text.erb) has no effect. When I add a new custom section, I get the following error in the log:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial exception_notifier/user with {:formats=>
[:text], :handlers=>[:haml, :rjs, :rhtml, :builder, :erb, :rxml], :locale=>[:de]} in
view paths "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/exception_notification-2.4.0/lib/exception_notifier/views"):
```

What am I doing wrong? I suspect that the view path is somehow messed up and that the exception_notifier doesn't bother to look in my /app/views/exception_notifier directory at all.

Comment: Seems to work as expected when used as plugin in vendor/plugins but not when used as gem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When exception_notification is used as a gem, the only view_path configured for the notifier is the gem own view path. 
In order to override default section template or add you your own you will have to add your application template folder in the view path

Just add to your initializer

```
 ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.prepend_view_path File.join(Rails.root, 'app/views')
```

If you have your own section partial don't forget to add it in the middleware options

```
 Whatever::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier,
   :email_prefix => "[Whatever] ",
   :sender_address => %{"notifier" <notifier@example.com>},
   :exception_recipients => %w{exceptions@example.com},
   :sections => %w{my_section1 my_section2} + ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.default_sections
```

Answer (score 2):

From version 2.6.0 of the gem and forth, this is no longer needed.
That bug is already fixed, so there's no need to have that line on an initializer anymore.

Comment: I seem to still be getting it on version 2.6.1.  It is automatically adding app/views to the end of the view_path, so that it finds the gem's views first, so overriding views isn't working.  I needed to add the initializer above to _prepend_ the override view path.